# Monotouch Logging Options

Tags: iphone, ipad, logging, xamarin.ios

When an iPhone or iPad app throws an error, what is the recommended way to get the data reported using Monotouch?

Comment: Please edit your question since its impossible to tell what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I simply use the Console.WriteLine, and a little wrapper around that, which helps me find the place and have some more information (like stacktrace and so on).

Console.WriteLine in MT writes to the device's console, so you can check it with the Organizer tool in XCode, and that really works well.

Am not sure if this is the recommended approach, but I use it, works well, and I personally can recommend it.